# jQuery animate() callback remembers only last variable in a loop

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-callback

I am writing a script which basically makes a box travel every time to different places and it does a specified numbers of loops. The movement of the box is just an `animate()` function, which is in a  while loop.

In this loop we also randomly select the coordinates to which the should go and comeback from. After it goes to the specified coordinates I insert a div to this exact location and make it red-colored. This I do in the callback function.

The problem that occurs is that a div is only added to the last coordinates which the box goes to.

```
var i =0;

while( i<5 ){ //specifying the cycles for the box' movement

var hstandWidth = $("#hstand").width()+27; //getting the current x-coordinates

//array to randomly select x-coordinates from 
var items = Array(hstandWidth-(50)*1, hstandWidth-(50)*2, hstandWidth-(50)*3, hstandWidth-(50)*4, hstandWidth-(50)*5,hstandWidth-(50)*6,hstandWidth-(50)*7,hstandWidth-(50)*8);                                         
//variable with the x-coordinates, which are randomly fetched from the array
var moveLeft = items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];

//array to randomly select y-coordinates from 
var items2 = Array(30,30*2,30*3,30*4,30*5,30*6,30*7);
//variable with the y-coordinates, which are randomly fetched from the array
var moveTop = items2[Math.floor(Math.random()*items2.length)];

// y-achs movement
$(this).animate({ "top"  : ""+ moveTop  +"px" }, 800);  
// x-achs movement with the callback function which should add the colored div to every position the box has been
$(this).animate({ "left" : ""+ moveLeft +"px" }, 800, function(){

$("<div style='position: absolute; top: "+moveTop+"px; left: "+moveLeft+"px; background: #ffcccc; width: 50px; height: 30px;'></div>").appendTo("#grid");

});                     
//get the box to the initial position
$(this).animate({"left": "0px"}, 800);
$(this).animate({"top" : "0px" }, 800);
//mark cycle passed
i++;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `moveTop` and `moveLeft` variables are being changed every time through the `for` loop so when the animation completes some time later, you only see the values at the end of the loop in the animation completion callback.  You can freeze the values each time through the loop with a closure like this:

```
var i =0;

while( i<5 ){ //specifying the cycles for the box' movement

    var hstandWidth = $("#hstand").width()+27; //getting the current x-coordinates

    //array to randomly select x-coordinates from 
    var items = Array(hstandWidth-(50)*1, hstandWidth-(50)*2, hstandWidth-(50)*3, hstandWidth-(50)*4, hstandWidth-(50)*5,hstandWidth-(50)*6,hstandWidth-(50)*7,hstandWidth-(50)*8);                                         
    //variable with the x-coordinates, which are randomly fetched from the array
    var moveLeft = items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];

    //array to randomly select y-coordinates from 
    var items2 = Array(30,30*2,30*3,30*4,30*5,30*6,30*7);
    //variable with the y-coordinates, which are randomly fetched from the array
    var moveTop = items2[Math.floor(Math.random()*items2.length)];

    // y-achs movement
    $(this).animate({ "top"  : ""+ moveTop  +"px" }, 800);  
    // x-achs movement with the callback function which should add the colored div to every position the box has been

    // create closure to capture moveTop and moveLeft values for later callback
    // use different named variables xmoveTop and xmoveLeft to distinguish the
    // closure variable from the outer for loop variable
    (function(obj, xmoveTop, xmoveLeft) {
        $(obj).animate({ "left" : ""+ xmoveLeft +"px" }, 800, function(){

            $("<div style='position: absolute; top: "+xmoveTop+"px; left: "+xmoveLeft+"px; background: #ffcccc; width: 50px; height: 30px;'></div>").appendTo("#grid");

        });
    })(this, moveTop, moveLeft);                     

    //get the box to the initial position
    $(this).animate({"left": "0px"}, 800);
    $(this).animate({"top" : "0px" }, 800);
    //mark cycle passed
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Hi, 10x for your answer but I'm not sure how to implement this in my code. Simply coppy-pasting it doesnt seem to work :S

Comment: @Stamenov - the change just affects the middle 5 lines of code.  If your code isn't working, then describe "what" isn't working and whether you are showing an errors in the console.  Also, please note that I changed `moveTop` to `xMoveTop` and `moveLeft` to `xmoveLeft` inside the closure.

Comment: Well firstly I just replaced my code with yours and the box istn't moving left and no divs are being added to the grid div.

Comment: It works now, thank you very much. Can you name the technique thath you used, so that I can do a little bit of research on it in the jQuery API website. Thank you!

Comment: @Stamenov - the technique has nothing to do with jQuery so it's probably not on the jQuery site.  It's called an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (often abbreviated IIFE) if you want to Google for it.  Its purpose is to create a function closure that captures the value of variables without that function scope so they stay what you want them to be for the lifetime of the code inside the function.

Comment: Hi again, I have a follow-up question. I want to make a div different color if the box was already there. I tried checking in the closure if the div exists and if it does to change the background color via jquery's css function. To do this I am setting an id to every div which contains the coordinates. Nevertheless it is not working.

Comment: (function(obj, xmoveTop, xmoveLeft) {
        $(obj).animate({ "left" : ""+ xmoveLeft +"px" }, 80, function(){
  
   if($("#"+xmoveLeft + xmoveTop +"").length > 0){
      
    $("#"+xmoveLeft + xmoveTop +"").css("background", "red");
   
   }else{
    $("<div style='position: absolute; top: "+xmoveTop+"px; left: "+xmoveLeft+"px; background: #ffcccc; width: 50px; height: 30px;' id='"+xmoveTop + xmoveLeft+"'></div>").appendTo("#grid");
   }
   
        });
    })(this, moveTop, moveLeft);

Comment: @Stamenov - I don't see anything conceptually wrong with your code so kind of hard to debug further without seeing at least an operative jsFiddle to look at.